# Add Item Drop Down List

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list which i filled with items from my database "mydatabase".

connect.php

```
<?php

    $dbname = 'mydatabase';
    $dbuser = 'louie';
    $dbpass = '';

    ?>
```

mydatabase contains the table 'Users' with 'Name' and 'NameID' column.

index.php

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

?>

<div class="label">Select Name:</div>

<select name="names" onchange="change(this.value)">
<option value = "none">---Select---</option>

<?php

    $query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `Users`";
    $mysqli = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

    while ($d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli)) {
        echo "<option value='{".$d['Name']."}'>".$d['Name']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>  

<select name="nid" id="nameid">
</select>
```

In my name column there is two values. Louie and Jane which fills the first dropdown "names". What I want to do is whenever I select the Louie, the second drop down with the id 'nameid' will be filled with the NameID column from my database.

I've got some idea in disabling the second drop down but without the database.

```
<script>
    function change(value) {
        if(value=="none")
            document.getElementById("nameid").disabled=true;
        else
            document.getElementById("nameid").disabled=false;
    }
</script>
```

But I don't know how to fill the second dropdown with NameID column by selecting the Louie in first drop down.

Comment: Put NameId in the value attribute of the first select options

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
x.text = value;
var s = document.getElementById("nameid");
s.add(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to understand that only PHP can access your database, and that reacting on UI changes is a javascript issue. That means that if you want the nameID on your second dropdown, php first needs to already provide it somewhere, and next you'll need some javascript to actually show it.

This is a possible solution:

```
<!-- note I changed the function onchange="change(this.value)" to onchange="change(this)"
because this.value is actually not the value.. -->
<select name="names" onchange="change(this)">
<option value = "none">---Select---</option>

<?php

// Select both columns you want to use in PHP
$query = "SELECT `NameID`, `Name` FROM `Users`";
$mysqli = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

// I used the value field to hold the id, rather than the name, while the name is shown to the user.
while ($d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli)) {
    echo "<option value='".$d['NameID']."'>".$d['Name']."</option>";
}

// your other code...
?>

<script>
    function change(oSelect) {
        var value = oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        var name = oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        if(name=="Louie") {
            document.getElementById('nameid').innerHTML = "";
            for (var i=0; i<oSelect.options; i++) {
                document.getElementById('nameid').innerHTML += "<option value='"+oSelect.options[i].value+"'>"+oSelect.options[i].value+"</option>";
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I select Louie, the first value in the NameID shows and when I select the second one, the second value in the NameID shows. I want to show all the values in NameID column if I only select the Louie..

Comment: I've modified the answer to check for name=="Louie" and then add ALL the options to the 2nd select. I can't for the life of me understand why you would want this ;) but I hope it helps

Comment: umm.. it's not working. There's no error but the NameID column is not appearing on the second drop down list